# Django admin CIDR type

Tags: python, django, admin, cidr

The problem is that I am working on a Django Admin project, which should be able to accept CIDR format data and put that into database (Postgres).

Let's say I have a model:

```
##################################################
class CIDR(models.Model):
    ....
    net_cidr = models.IPAddressField(unique=True)
    ....

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.net_cidr

##################################################
```

Based on the above code, the `net_cidr` field in the database is of inet type, which supports the CIDR format data. However, `IPAddressField` doesn't support CIDR (at least doesn't work for me). If I want to enter something on my admin site like "128.66.0.0/16", Django will pop an error, telling me to "Enter a valid IPv4 address".

I have tried to change the field type to Char, and it works (of course). However, it is not a good idea to set CIDR as varchar in the database.

Basically what I want is to let `net_cidr` to be able to accpet an IP Range, like "128.66.0.0-128.66.255.255" or a CIDR block "128.66.0.0/16" and save it to database as 
"128.66.0.0/16".

I think the key part is how to let `IPAddressField` accept a string type (like an IP range or CIDR block) data. Then I can convert it to CIDR block and save it to database.

Comment: CIDR is not an IP address format. It is used for representing networks. Probably you could use django's RegexField to achieve what you want.

Comment: @rantanplan: The problem is that RegexField is a Form Field, how do I use it in my model? module "models" dosen't have such field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you need.

What I would do is to define `net_cidr` as a `models.CharField`.

Then define a modelform for your model where you are going to implement
the `clean_net_cidr` function.

```
class CIDRForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_net_cidr(self):
        # do your magic processing here

    class Meta:
        model = CIDR
```

and then pass that form to the model admin object

```
class CIDRAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CIDRForm
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems this is exactly what you need, based on your comments.
https://github.com/jimfunk/django-postgresql-netfields

Among other fields, it includes a `CidrAddressField`

Comment: Actually, I have tried this before. It works, really. However, if you take a look at the database schema, you will notice that data type for net_cidr is varchar. For my admin site. It is not problem, but there are someone else need to apply other scripts to the database and they need this net_cidr as inet type. Thank you for you advice, though.

Comment: I think I have a way to do so. Define net_cidr as IPAddressField in model and override it in form as CharField. For now, it solved my problem.

Comment: @FanyongMeng yes, it is similar to my suggestion, but in the link I mention in my update you'll see that it provides the *native* postgresql `cidr` type.

Comment: Ha, you know what, I tried that, too. I think that works, but not for me. I don't know why it keep pop some silly error when I try to apply it to my app. I even tried to contact the guy who commit it^_^. Anyway, I think I found a way to solve it. Thanks dude~

Comment: @FanyongMeng Hmm interesting. They do mention a couple of bugs which they attribute to django code and not their implementation. Anyway, you're welcome.